# Polymer : TypeError: Attempting to change access mechanism for an unconfigurable property

Tags: javascript, ios, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a project on Polymer 1.0 and i use GULP to compile it in production. it work well for almost all platform exempt on older iOS.

on iOS, i can see with jsconsole.com two errors :

> TypeError: Attempting to change access mechanism for an unconfigurable
>   property.
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.__data__[t]')

those errors never happend on desktop or android with Chrome.

have you any clue or gulp option a could try ?

thx

Comment: Which version of iOS? As per Polymer documentation support is only for 7+ with `polyfill`. You can check the version support [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/browsers)

Comment: my old iphone is 7.1.2 but the other iphone is 9.3.2 it didnt work in safari but work in chrome.